# Behavior of 'subsref' for arrays of objects

Tags: matlab, overriding

Imagine a simple array of structures, say:

```
A = struct('x', {1 2 3}, 'y', {'a' 'b' 'c'});
```

Asking for a given property for all this array's elements will give something like:

```
>> A.x
ans =
     1
ans =
     2
ans =
     3
```

Now, if I explicitly call the subsref function directly on this array, it only retrieves the first element's property:

```
>> builtin('subsref', A, substruct('.', 'x'))
ans = 
     1
```

Why? And is there a possibility to call explicitly another built-in method that will retrieve the property for all the array's elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subsref` method can return it but not as a [comma separated list](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) the way you get it in the interpreter. It returns them as separate output arguments that means:

```
>> [a,b,c]=builtin('subsref', A(:), substruct('.', 'x'))
a =
     1
b =
     2
c =
     3
```

you can capture the output in a cell array if you like

```
>> [x{1:numel(A)}]=builtin('subsref', A(:), substruct('.', 'x'))
x = 
    [1]    [2]    [3]
```

Comment: what is this syntax called for "[x{1:numel(dt)}]"  and why does it work?