# Access complex matlab struct with function/string

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab struct which several levels (e.g. a.b(j).c(i).d). I would like to write a function which gives me the fields I want. If the struct has only one level, it would be easy:

```
function x = test(struct, label1)
  x = struct.(label1)
end
```

E.g. if I have the struct `a.b` I could get `b` via: `test('b')`. However, this does not work with subfields, if I have a struct `a.b.c` I can't use `test('b.c')` to access it.

Is there any way to pass a string with the full field name (with dots) to a function to retrieve this field? Or is there even a better way to get only the fields that I select through the function arguments?

The goal? Sure, it would be a useless function for one fieldname, but I wan't to pass a list of fieldnames as argument to receive exactly these fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `subsref` function:

```
function x = test(strct, label1)
F=regexp(label1, '\.', 'split');
F(2:2:2*end)=F;
F(1:2:end)={'.'};
x=subsref(strct, substruct(F{:}));
end
```

To access `a.b.c` you can use:

```
subsref(a, substruct('.', 'b', '.', 'c'));
```

The test function first splits the input using `.`as a delimiter and creates a cell array `F` where every other element is filled with `.` and then its elements are passed to `substruct` as arguments.

Note that if there are arrays of `structs` involved it will get the first one. For `a.b(i).c(j).d` passing `b.c.d` will return `a.b(1).c(1).d`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236807/behavior-of-subsref-for-arrays-of-objects) for the way it should be handled.

As a side note, I renamed your input variable `struct` to `strct` because `struct` is a built-in MATLAB command.

Comment: Sorry for being absent so long, this solution works great for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a **self calling** function to do this:

```
a.b.c.d.e.f.g = 'abc'
value = getSubField ( a, 'b.c.d.e.f.g' )

  'abc'

function output = getSubField ( myStruct, fpath )
  % convert the provided path to a cell
  if ~iscell(fpath); fpath = strread ( fpath, '%s', 'delimiter', '.' ); end
  % extract the field (should really check if it exists)
  output = myStruct.(fpath{1});
  % remove the one we just found
  fpath(1) = [];
  % if fpath still has items in it -> self call to get the value
  if isstruct ( output ) && ~isempty(fpath)
    % Pass in the sub field and the remaining fpath
    output = getSubField ( output, fpath );
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work, but the other solution looks more clear to me.